# Python: TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Tags: python

Пайтон ругается на вот такое вот.

**TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing**

Понять не могу где тут ошибка.

```
 for number in range(0,len(list)):
                if list[number] == summa:
                            code
```

Comment: А кто такой `list`? Python считает, что это -- множество.

Comment: Глядя на ваш код хочется привести совет Марка Лутца из его книги "Изучаем Python":

> Не пишите на C

Под этим Лутц имел ввиду то, что не нужно на Python писать в том же стиле, что и на C. В частности - перебирать элементы коллекций через индексы, игнорируя столь удобный инструмент как итераторы. В отличие от C, доступ к элементам коллекции (особенно если это какая-то кастомная коллекция) по индексам может быть достаточно дорогим. Если же при переборе важны индексы, используйте функцию [`enumerate()`][1].

  [1]: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

могу предположить что list в вашем случае это set, а с ним нельзя делать так list[number]

В любом случае вы все делаете неправильно.

Во-первых не называйте переменную list, так вы замените стандартную питоновскую команду

Во-вторых перепишите свой код так:

```
for n in my_list:
    if n == summa:
        print 'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

`list` у Вас является множеством, а у него нет индексов - это просто множество объектов.

Попробуйте так:

```
for list_element in list:
                if list_element == summa:
                            code
```